# Set text on the start of div

Tags: html, css

I want to set text on the start of div like where the div upper border.
But when I increase font size it left some white space on the top.

```
   <div id="preview">
       <div id="custom">
             <div id="t1"><span>First text</span></div>
             <div id="t2"><span>Second text</span></div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Here is css.

```
       #t1{
          font-size:30px;
       }
       #t2{
          font-size:100px;
       }
```

And there is also white space between first text and second text I don't want these white space between them and around div.
Just text start on the top where first text end below this start the second text with out any white space.

Answer (score 0):

That is default behavior of text. However if you want to do it you can give margin left in negative(however its not good practice) or you can use positioning.

```
 #t1{
              font-size:30px;
           }
           #t2{
              font-size:100px;
margin-left: -4px;
           }
```

Comment: Yes I know and I want to prevent this default behavior how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `line-height` in css is an option:

```
#t1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 75%;
}
#t2 {
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 75%;
}
```

Comment: but this is not work for every font size let suppose if there is third text with 300px then what ?

Comment: @AzeemHaider you can always play with the numbers and try to get what you desire. Do 70%, do 65%. See what's the best for you. How am i supposed to know which one is the best for you.

Comment: Problem is that font size is randomly generate for each text so I can not fix any specific value. This is not working for me.